# why django signal not working with custom User model?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I am creating a Django signup form through `User` model and `UserCreationForm` and customized the `User` model to accommodate single user defined field `contact`.

### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class SignUp(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Contact = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        SignUp.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

### forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from  .models import SignUp

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
#    phone = format()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')


class CustomSignUpPage(forms.ModelForm):
    Contact = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
    class Meta:
        model = SignUp
        fields = ('Contact', )
```

### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages
#from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .forms import SignUpForm, CustomSignUpPage

def home(request):
   return render(request, 'authenticate\home.html', {})

def login_user(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      username = request.POST['username']
      password = request.POST['password']
      user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
      if user is not None:
         login(request, user)
         messages.success(request, ('login success'))
         return redirect('home')
      else:
         messages.success(request, ('error while login, please try again'))
         return redirect('login')
   else:
      return render(request, 'authenticate\login.html', {})

def logout_user(request):
   logout(request)
   messages.success(request, ('logout successful'))
   return redirect('home')

# def register_user(request):
#    if request.method == "POST":
#       form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
#       if form.is_valid():
#          form.save()
#          username = form.cleaned_data['username']
#          password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
#          user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
#          login(request, user)
#          messages.success(request, ('Registration successful'))
#          return redirect('home')
#    else:
#       form = UserCreationForm()
#    return render(request, 'authenticate\\register.html', context={'form': form})

def register_user(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
      form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
      cus_form = CustomSignUpPage(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid() and cus_form.is_valid():
         save1 = form.save()
         save1.refresh_from_db()
         cus_form = CustomSignUpPage(request.POST, instance=save1.AUTHENTICATION)
         cus_form.full_clean()
         cus_form.save()
         username = form.cleaned_data['username']
         password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
         user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
         login(request, user)
         messages.success(request, f'Registration successful')
         return redirect('home')
      else:
         messages.error(request, f'Please correct the error below.')
   else:
      form = SignUpForm()
      cus_form = CustomSignUpPage()

   return render(request, 'authenticate\\register.html', context={'form': form, 'cus_form': cus_form})
```

However, the signal that I have written seems not to be working. I have followed a blog which is below:

```
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html
```

Whenever, I am filling the form, I am getting below error:

```
AttributeError at /auth/register/
'User' object has no attribute 'profile'
```

Below is the full Traceback logs:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/register/

Django Version: 3.0.5
Python Version: 3.8.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'phone_field',
 'AUTHENTICATION']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anshu\djago-project\SkoolSkill\AUTHENTICATION\views.py", line 50, in register_user
    save1 = form.save()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 137, in save
    user.save()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 66, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 745, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 793, in save_base
    post_save.send(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 173, in send
    return [
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 174, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "C:\Users\anshu\djago-project\SkoolSkill\AUTHENTICATION\models.py", line 17, in save_user_profile
    instance.profile.save()

Exception Type: AttributeError at /auth/register/
Exception Value: 'User' object has no attribute 'profile'
```

I have uploaded the project in google drive with below location link, just in case if somebody wishes to test it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1COB3BBoRb95a85cLi9k1PdIYD3bmlnc0/view?usp=sharing

My environment:

Django==3.0.5
python 3.8.2

Not sure what is the mistake. Please help

Answer (score 0):

it looks like this signal is throwing:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

I think the issue is the User model does not have a profile field: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#user-objects

Comment: Yes, that receiver is causing the issue. Since I am adding a user defined form field "Contact". So, I wansted to use signal for that. Now I have used "Contact" instead of "profile", yet I face issues. Not sure I am doing the right thing.

Comment: ok to access the signup you would do something like `instance.signup `  if you would like to acces the contact field it would  be `instance.signup.contact`
calling the save method on the signup model there makes no sense since it should have been created and saved bevore (the other signal) and you didn't change it.

 what is your goal with this signal what should it do/change?

Comment: My goal is to update the "Contact" field through my forms.py, and that is why I am trying to use signal. I am working with Signal for the first time, and I have implemented what I understood. If the user defined field "contact" could be worked without the signal, even that would work for me.

Comment: Going forward, I followed your instructions and replaced "instance.signup.save()" with "instance.signup.Contact". So, this time, the error moved toward the views.py at line 52, which happens to be "cus_form = CustomSignUpPage(request.POST, instance=request.save1.signup.contact)". The error is "AttributeError at /auth/register/
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'save1".      But I have used "save1" to save the form. Please have a look on the views.py in the original post. Thank you again.

Comment: just a question in this comment you write `instance=request.save1.signup.contact`

and in the updated post i don't see this line

and also the request does not get the save1 variable this is only a local variable

Comment: so about your goal you don't need a signal for that it can be done in the view

Comment: Sorry for that, I am doing some or the other testing, so I have copy pasted the latest testing. Coming back to the issue, neither the "instance=request.save1.signup.contact", nor the "instance=request.save1.AUTHENTICATION". The later will never work, as it was obviously wrong. So, could you please give me the code snippet that I should use in my project's view.py to use the user defined field "Contact" without the use of signal? that would be a great help.

Comment: as said before the `request` object does not have the local variable save1

ensure that your request data contains the data of both forms, you might have to use inlineformsets https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

also check this article it might help:
https://dev.to/zxenia/django-inline-formsets-with-class-based-views-and-crispy-forms-14o6